# Not getting "ModifiedDate" for ListSend Endpoint

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, marketingcloudapi

I am using `ET_ListSend`.

But when I am fetching records I am not getting `ModifedDate` for the sends, but it is given in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/listsend.html#properties)

Is anyone facing the same issue?

Is there any way to get the data with the `ModifiedDate` field?

Here is my code:

```
import FuelSDK
params = {
        'clientid': 'clientid123',
        'clientsecret': 'clientsecret123',
        'tenant_subdomain': 'tenant_subdomain123'}

my_client = FuelSDK.ET_Client(params=params)
list_send = FuelSDK.ET_ListSend()
list_send.auth_stub = my_client

results = list_send.get()
print(results.results)
```

And the response I got:

```
(ListSend)
{
   Client = 
      (ClientID){
         ID = 1234567
      }
   PartnerKey = None
   ObjectID = None
   SendID = 12345
   List = 
      (List){
         PartnerKey = None
         ID = 54321
         ObjectID = None
         ListName = "Dummy List"
      }
   Duplicates = 0
   InvalidAddresses = 0
   ExistingUndeliverables = 0
   ExistingUnsubscribes = 0
   HardBounces = 0
   SoftBounces = 0
   OtherBounces = 0
   ForwardedEmails = 0
   UniqueClicks = 0
   UniqueOpens = 1
   NumberSent = 1
   NumberDelivered = 1
   Unsubscribes = 0
   MissingAddresses = 0
   PreviewURL = "dummy_url.com"
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the code-- preferably the SOAP envelope.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a describe on the SOAP object `ListSend` shows that `ModifiedDate` is NOT retrievable, which is why you are not getting it in your returned object.

[image]

using the following request to get this info via SOAP Envelope:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Describe</a:Action>
        <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://{{et_subdomain}}.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>
        <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">{{dne_etAccessToken}}</fueloauth>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <DefinitionRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
         <DescribeRequests>
            <ObjectDefinitionRequest>
               <ObjectType>ListSend</ObjectType>
            </ObjectDefinitionRequest>
         </DescribeRequests>
      </DefinitionRequestMsg>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Is there any way to make

`IsRetrievable = True`?

Comment: That is controlled by SFMC and not something we can alter